# Alternatives to WinForms app data storage - many problems with SqlCE

Tags: winforms, sql-server-ce, local-storage

I am struggling to make a SqlCE local database to work in my winforms project.

I`m used to work with web app, this is my first desktop app, and after understand a lot of tricks like when you insert data in your local database while debugging, the data goes to a magic database inside bin/debug folder - that I would never wonder by myself - and from yesterday to now, I launch my project again, and guess what the new trick? The database got lost ¬¬ !!

Suddenly my project can't recognize its own path to the database and it throws me an error: "The path is not from a legal form", I SWEAR I didn't move the mouse from yesterday when it was working from now.

Anyway, SqlCE gave me a lot of headaches already, I'm doing this project as a favor to a bookstore inside a charity house and I'd like this project gets only one weekend - it already didn't.

So, as I don`t have a big amount of data to store, what would be the alternatives to store this data without a .sdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay with SQL I would recommend SQLite. Small, lightweight and results are placed in a single file.

http://sqlite.org/